# iOS create JSON file as sample data to test network and parsing logic

Tags: ios, json

I'm working with an project dealing with send request to server and get JSON response. Is there a way to create a offline JSON file as sample data so that the app read from sample data file instead of making real network request? I want to test the JSON `parsing` and `mapping` before write `network` call

For example, how can we make a JSON file from this JSON?

```
{
  "by" : "dhouston",
  "descendants" : 71,
  "id" : 8863,
  "kids" : [ 8952, 9224, 8917, 8884, 8887, 8943, 8869, 8958, 9005, 9671, 9067, 8940, 8908, 9055, 8865, 8881, 8872, 8873, 8955, 10403, 8903, 8928, 9125, 8998, 8901, 8902, 8907, 8894, 8878, 8980, 8870, 8934, 8876 ],
  "score" : 111,
  "time" : 1175714200,
  "title" : "My YC app: Dropbox - Throw away your USB drive",
  "type" : "story",
  "url" : "http://www.getdropbox.com/u/2/screencast.html"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to serialize, post and get a json back:

```
    let json = ["by":"dhouston","descendants":"71"]

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])

        let url = NSURL(string: "your url")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data,response,error in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!.localizedDescription)

                return
            }

            let header = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            print(header.allHeaderFields)

            do {

                let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: String] // your json response for example [String: String], depends on what you get as a response
                print(responseObject)

                // do something

            } catch let jsonError {
                print(jsonError)
                print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

if you just want to serialize use:

```
let json = ["by":"dhouston","descendants":"71"]

do {
      let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
   } catch {
      print(error)
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Save your json file in your main bundle, then you can read it as json data, followed by parsing:

```
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jsonfile", ofType: "json")
        let data = Data(contentsOf: URL(string: filePath)!)

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
        } catch error {
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: thanks. How to create a file? just an empty .json file and place to main bundle?

Comment: use your favorite editor to create a json file with your sample data, save it to the disk. Then drag it to your iOS project in XCode, choose "Copy..."

Answer (score 1):

Create new file with Strings by ***Xcode->New->File->String File*** 
Rename file with **File.json**

Use below code **SWIFT 3.x** for picking `.json` file

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let sampleDataPath = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("File.json").path
        print(sampleDataPath)
     }
```